# How to fix this error : psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I try to connect to pgsql via ssh  :

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ psql
psql: FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist
```

As you can see I got this error message  `'psql: FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist'`

I use vm-box in windows OS

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure postgres to allow vagrant to connect from local machine ? Out of the box, only the `postgres` user is configured. Try `sudo -u postgres -i` followed by `psql`.

Answer (score 6):

I think I found it !

```
psql -U homestead -h localhost
```

then the password and it works !